# How to get GCC/++4.6 or newer on Debian

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, debian

--version shows up 4.4 on Debian Squeeze. Today I left Ubuntu because its simply not stable (about 50++ errors a day) and slow. And I dont like Unity. Debian is great. Reliable, fast and Gnome 2 is okay. I worked on a large c++ project and made heavy use of c++0x features.

**My question is: how do I get at least gcc 4.6 on Debian?**

Running a mixed system is no option. I mean changing sources.list and upgrade. And full upgrade is no option because of Gnome 3. I will have to wait for Debian MATE. But somehow this has to be accomplished...

Comment: I take it building GCC yourself isn't an option?

Comment: what did you try? Doesn't apt-get gcc-4.6 work?

Comment: @Sebastian - I think gcc-4.6 is only in wheezy and sid.

Comment: Yes apt-get shows 4.4 too. I never build a compiler myself. I ask you. Is it an option?

Comment: Building your own gcc is not very difficult, and you don't need to install any packages on your machine if you don't want to. Follow the instructions at http://gcc.gnu.org/install/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build the [GCC 4.7](http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.7/) (from its FSF source tar ball). This might be painful (it really depends upon your skills), and may take several hours of CPU. Before compiling it, install all the required dependencies (perhaps by compiling them from their source code), and read carefully the [GCC install](http://gcc.gnu.org/install/) documentation several times.

<sup>I am not sure that you are right in avoiding mixing Debian/testing with Debian/stable. I am happily using Debian/unstable on all my desktops and laptops, so I get the latest released GCC.</sup>

When you build GCC 4.7.2 from the FSF source tarball, don't forget to build *outside of the source tree*. Read carefully about the configure options (you probably want `--program-suffix=-4.7` for instance). Don't forget to enable plugins (with `--enable-plugin` at `..../configure` time) in your GCC. You could perhaps be interested by [MELT](http://gcc-melt.org/), a domain specific language to extend GCC, implemented as a [meta-] plugin.

If you dislike Gnome3 -which I do understand- you might try another Debian based distribution like [Linux Mint](http://linuxmint.com/), or simply use XFCE as your desktop.

Comment: "you might try another Debian based distribution" ...Thats what I did. After I messed up my system. :( Now on debian testing. Everything works fine. And even though it's testing, it is stunningly more stable as Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 1):

You can install certain packages from testing while the others remain stable. See [APT Preferences](http://wiki.debian.org/AptPreferences) from the debian wiki.

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want to do. A mixed system will end up in a mess with unresolved dependencies.